# Error while updating Castle.Windsor to 3.3

Tags: castle-windsor

I am updating my project from Castle.Windsor 2.5.4 to 3.3.0.
I get an error:

> The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.
>
> 1) GenericArguments[0], 'TInterface', on 'Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.ComponentRegistration`1[TService]' 
>   violates the constraint of type parameter 'TService'.

It's while it tries to resolve:

```
IActiveRequestService requestService = _container.Resolve<IActiveRequestService>();

public interface IActiveRequestService
{
    void SetActiveRequest(IActiveRequest request);
    IActiveRequest Current { get; }
    void ClearActiveRequest();
    bool HasActiveRequest { get; }
    void StartAcceptingRequests();
    void StopAcceptingRequests(string Reason);
    bool IsAcceptingRequests { get; }
    string ReasonRequestRejected { get; }
}
```

Comment: That message to me indicates the error is occurring where you are registering components.  Can you verify the line the exception is thrown on, or post the exception's stack trace?

Comment: Make sure you Clean/Recompile your code. That should produce a compilation error, not a runtime error.